# EditText Value is same as that of the first row in ListView

Tags: java, android

EditText - `holder.ednum.setText` is setting the same value for both the first Item and the lastitem(Fourth) in the ListView 
Ex if I press the plus icon for the first row in the ListView (Please Refer Image) the value gets changed for the first Item as well as the last Item in the Listview. It has to do something with holder.ednum, but I'm unsure on how to fix this issue.

Please see the screenshot to get perfect idea of my problem:

[image]

```
  package com.freshmenu.mylistview;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.pavan.mylistview.R;

public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public int max_range = 9;

    public int min_range = 0;

    int initialvalues = 0;

    String filepath = "/storage/sdcard0/FreshGrub/";

    String filepath1 = "/item.jpg";

    int initialvalues2 = 0;

    int pos;

    Context context;

    RowItem row_pos;

    List<RowItem> rowItems;

    RowItem selectedRowItem;

    CustomAdapter( Context context , List<RowItem> rowItems ) {

        this.context = context;
        this.rowItems = rowItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return rowItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem( int position ) {

        return rowItems.get( position );
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId( int position ) {

        return rowItems.indexOf( getItem( position ) );
    }

    /* private view holder class */
    public class ViewHolder {

        ImageView profile_pic;

        TextView member_name;

        TextView status;

        TextView contactType;

        ImageButton plus;

        ImageButton minus;

        EditText ednum;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView( int position , View convertView , ViewGroup parent ) {

        final ViewHolder holder;

        LayoutInflater mInflater = ( LayoutInflater ) context.getSystemService( Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );

        if ( convertView == null ) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate( R.layout.list_item , null );
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.member_name = ( TextView ) convertView.findViewById( R.id.member_name );
            holder.profile_pic = ( ImageView ) convertView.findViewById( R.id.profile_pic );
            holder.status = ( TextView ) convertView.findViewById( R.id.state );

            //holder.profile_pic.setImageResource( row_pos.getProfile_pic_id() );

            holder.ednum = ( EditText ) convertView.findViewById( R.id.ednum );
            holder.plus = ( ImageButton ) convertView.findViewById( R.id.plus );
            holder.minus = ( ImageButton ) convertView.findViewById( R.id.minus );

            convertView.setTag( holder );
        } else {
            holder = ( ViewHolder ) convertView.getTag();
        }

        row_pos = rowItems.get( position );
        Bitmap bitmap = decodeSampledBitmapFromPath( filepath + row_pos.getStatus() + filepath1 , 400 , 225 );
        holder.profile_pic.setImageBitmap( bitmap );

        //holder.profile_pic.setImageResource( row_pos.getProfile_pic_id() );
        holder.member_name.setText( row_pos.getMember_name() );

        holder.plus.setFocusable( false );
        holder.minus.setFocusable( false );

        holder.plus.setTag( position );
        holder.minus.setTag( position );
        holder.ednum.setTag( position );

        holder.plus.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick( View v ) {

                String tag = v.getTag().toString();
                if ( tag != null ) {

                    pos = Integer.parseInt( tag );
                    selectedRowItem = rowItems.get( pos );
                }

                //initialvalues = selectedRowItem.getInitialValues();
                String initialvalues = selectedRowItem.getInitialValues();
                int finalInitialvalues = Integer.parseInt( initialvalues );

                if ( finalInitialvalues >= min_range && finalInitialvalues <= max_range )
                    finalInitialvalues++;
                else
                    finalInitialvalues = 0;
                selectedRowItem.setInitialValues( finalInitialvalues + "" );
                if ( finalInitialvalues > max_range )
                    finalInitialvalues = min_range;
                //holder.ednum.setText( row_pos.getMember_name() );
                holder.ednum.setText( "    " + finalInitialvalues );

            }

        } );

        holder.minus.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick( View v ) {

                String tag = v.getTag().toString();
                if ( tag != null ) {

                    pos = Integer.parseInt( tag );
                    selectedRowItem = rowItems.get( pos );
                }
                //initialvalues = selectedRowItem.getInitialValues();
                String initialvalues = selectedRowItem.getInitialValues();
                int finalInitialvalues = Integer.parseInt( initialvalues );
                if ( finalInitialvalues >= min_range && finalInitialvalues <= max_range )
                    finalInitialvalues--;
                else {
                    finalInitialvalues = 9;

                }
                selectedRowItem.setInitialValues( finalInitialvalues + "" );
                if ( finalInitialvalues < min_range )
                    finalInitialvalues = max_range;

                holder.ednum.setText( "    " + finalInitialvalues );
            }
        } );

        return convertView;
    }

    private ImageView findViewById( int profilePic ) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    protected void finish() {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromPath( String path , int reqWidth , int reqHeight ) {

        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile( path , options );

        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize( options , reqWidth , reqHeight );

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile( path , options );
        return bmp;
    }

    public static int calculateInSampleSize( BitmapFactory.Options options , int reqWidth , int reqHeight ) {

        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if ( height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth ) {
            if ( width > height ) {
                inSampleSize = Math.round( ( float ) height / ( float ) reqHeight );
            } else {
                inSampleSize = Math.round( ( float ) width / ( float ) reqWidth );
            }
        }
        return inSampleSize;
    }

}
```

Comment: I wonder why did you add  holder.member_name = ( TextView ) convertView.findViewById( R.id.member_name ); when the convert view is not null. You have to initialize the components only when the convert view is null then set holder tag on the else block you just get the holder and do your logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be in your getView() method.

```
if ( convertView == null ) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate( R.layout.list_item , null );
        holder = new ViewHolder();

     // here you should only initialise(findViewById) all your views 
     // remember don't set any values to your TextView/ImageViews here

      convertView.setTag( holder );

    } else {
        holder = ( ViewHolder ) convertView.getTag();
   }

 // here you should set value of your TextViews and ImageViews and your clickListeners
```

Comment: ,Thanks for the suggestion , i have made the the changes as mentioned by you  but still i am facing same problem... Please see my edited code

Comment: Remove first line(convertView.setTag( holder );) from here
 convertView.setTag( holder );
        holder.plus.setTag( position );
        holder.minus.setTag( position );
        holder.ednum.setTag( position );

NO need to set tag again once it is being set in your if( convertView == null ) this condition

Comment: the problem is your are not setting value to your editext(ednum) anywhere, you are only setting it on some click event. Since your views are recycling, so you have to set the value of your EditText everytime

Comment: Thanks a lot..You are super.. Finally it is working.. :)